# Is it possible to limit the number of periods for stripe recuring subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments

One found 2 modals:

Recurring:
Charge an ongoing fee

One-off:
Charge a one-off fee

Is that possible to have subscription that charge monthly and total 3 month then auto cancel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact UTC time you want to cancel the Subscription, you can use the `cancel_at` parameter when [creating the Subscription](https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-cancel_at). Please note that if you do not calculate the exact timestamp for the billing period end, the final invoice will be prorated. You can test this behavior using their [Test Clocks](https://docs.stripe.com/billing/testing/test-clocks) to simulate this behavior in test mode.

Alternatively, they also have [Subscription Schedules](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules) that helps plan future changes to Subscriptions. You can create a Subscription with [`cancel_at_period_end: true`](https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-cancel_at_period_end) to automatically cancel at the end of that billing period. Then, when you create the [Subscription Schedule from that Subscription](https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscription_schedules/create#create_subscription_schedule-from_subscription) you can use the [`phases.iterations`](https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscription_schedules/create#create_subscription_schedule-phases-iterations) which is a multiplier applied to the price interval telling it how many times it would need to be iterated. Once the iterations are complete, the subscription will be automatically cancelled.

Or, the final option I could think of is to track this on your end, and on the last month you can make a call to [update the Subscription](https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at_period_end) and set `cancel_at_period_end` to true.

Comment: Thank you @pgs. Is it possible to config that in the payment link? It always show xxx per month, whether actually I only want tit 1/2 month. Appreciate